# Convert Loop To Linq - Model Creation

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm converting an entity object to a model that can be passed around my application without the extra overhead (As well as generating a couple of extra fields for the view etc.

```
        public IEnumerable<PageModel> GetAllPages()
        {
            var AllPageO = _session.All<Page>();

            IList<PageModel> RetO = new List<PageModel>();

            foreach (var AP in AllPageO)
            {
                RetO.Add(new PageModel(AP));
            }

            return RetO.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Can this be converted to a Linq Query, the below does work I get the error

> Server Error in '/' Application. Only
>   parameterless constructors and
>   initializers are supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

```
    public IEnumerable<PageModel> GetAllPages()
    {
        var AllPageO = _session.All<Page>();

        var RetO = from EntityO in AllPageO select new PageModel(EntityO);

        return RetO;
    }
```

Resharper actually converts the firt loop into this, which also fails with the same error.

```
IList<PageModel> RetO = PageO.Select(AP => new PageModel(AP)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because entity framework is trying to convert optimize your projection expression into sql.

The easy fix is to enumerate the results before the projection:

```
 var RetO = from EntityO in AllPageO.ToList() select new PageModel(EntityO);
```

Comment: Great, I knew this. It just somehow slipped from my mind. Cheers jfar.